# CSS: background image only shows on first occurring div on page

Tags: html, css

I have a problem which has me stumped. I have it simplified down to this. The relevant (only) CSS style is:

```
    #segment1,
    #segment2 {
         width: 16.6667%;
         height: 100%;
         float: left;
         background-image: url(../XYZ-TEST/1alt.gif); 
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-attachment: fixed;
         background-position: top left;
     }
```

and the relevant test HTML is:

```
    <div id="segment1">Segment one</div>
    <div id="segment2">Segment two</div>
```

So you think you'd get two identical divs side by side, with the same background image - except when it is rendered, the background image ONLY appears on the first occurring . The problem appears to be on the rendering, not the code. If I put the HTML for segment2 first, that one gets the background image and the other one doesn't. Other CSS seems fine, just the background image fails. The path to the background image is fine.

It looks like a problem within CSS with defining multiple background images, but I can't find any other problem like it mentioned on the web. Tested in both Chrome and FF. I've ruled out a stray semi-colon or similar, because both are defined simultaneously. Can you see anything I've missed ?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: I guess the container (of the 2 divs) has a fixed height and the important thing is it also has `overflow:hidden` set, so one div will be clipped off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `background-attachment:fixed` from css. It should solve your issue.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/256/

```
#segment1, #segment2 {
     width: 16.6667%;
     height: 100%;
     float: left;
     background-image: url(http://www-mtl.mit.edu/img/bg_01.gif);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;     
     background-position: top left;
 }
```

Explanation: `If a background-image is specified, the background-attachment CSS property determines whether that image's position is fixed within the viewport, or scrolls along with its containing block.`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated ! I thought I had trimmed down the css to the bare minimum to debug, but hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @K K, I tried your suggestion, but for me it didn't work. How would I solve this problem? I am using react and css to style the JSX.